# why Autowiring with request bean not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, autowired

I have following classes :

**Class 1**

```
package com.assets;
@Component 
@Scope("request)
public class AssetDetailsImpl implements AssetApi
{
    public void function1(){
    ....
    }

    public void function2(){
    new AssetUtil().test1();
    }

}
```

**Class 2**

```
package com.assets;
@Component 
public class AssetUtil
{
   @Autowired
   AssetDetailsImpl impl;
   //some functions
   public void test1{
    impl.function1();// NPE I amm getting
}
```

here my autowiring not working, its coming null. both the classes in same package. Is it because of the **request scope** which is there in AssetDetailsImpl? I even tried with @**Inject** that also was not working
Can anyone please help me to resolve this??
Thanks in advance!

***Edit : I have tried removing the scope, but then also the same problem.***

Comment: A few pointers. Firstly, try to inject the dependency using a constructor injection. This will potentially reveal problems that field injection tends to hide. Secondly, why is our bean scope for `request`?

Comment: @tgdavies yes i tried, seems not workin

Comment: @akortex my I tried removing scope but then also didnt work. Also I tried making through constructor : AssetDetailsImpl impl = new AssetDetailsImpl(); that was also coming null

Answer (score 0):

Class 2 need a constructor like this to work:

```
AssetUtil(AssetDetailsImpl impl) {
    this.impl = impl;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so how this constructor will be invoked ?  as from detailsImpl class I am calling     new AssetUtil().test1();

Comment: @TechGeek: if you do `new AssetUtil()` then **no** dependency injection of any kind will happen, you're using it wrong.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I made it static and called it with classname, but then also its not working. Then how should I use it?

Comment: @TechGeek: for Spring to be able to inject stuff, it needs to have touched it. In other words: inject the `AssetUtil` into your classes or otherwise request it from Spring.